# Razor ActionLink goofy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This Razor tag:

```
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
```

renders like this:

```
[ Log On (/ACCOUNT/LOGON) ][/code]
```

This is the generated HTML:

```
[ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]
```

How do I keep it from doing this or does it just do it in debug mode?
If it does, that is kind of stupid because it messes up my view of my template.

Also, how do I do this in Razor:

```
<a href="http://myexternallink.com"><img alt="external" src="@Url.Content("./Content/themes/base/images/spacer.gif")" class="icoExternal"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax

```
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
```

simply throws an exception as it is invalid syntax.

Assuming default routes:

```
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
```

Renders:

```
[ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]
```

in all modes (Debug, Release, whatever) which is the expected behavior.

> How do I keep it from doing this

That's the expected behavior, I don't understand why do you want to keep it from doing this? If you don't want the square brackets simply remove them:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")
```

As far as your second question is concerned:

```
<a href="http://myexternallink.com">
    <img alt="external" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/spacer.gif")" class="icoExternal" />
</a>
```

Comment: Even though the HTML renders fine, why would it look like this: http://www.scic.com/files/eddie/mvc3_1.png

Comment: I've already tried the way on the second question with horrible results.

Comment: @MB34, oh no, it doesn't look like this at all. `[ <a href="/Account/LogOn">Log On</a> ]` will look like this: `[ LogOn ]`. I don't know where you are getting this result from. As far as the second question is concerned what do you mean by horrible results? I am not sure I understand you. You have some CSS problems?

Comment: I know it should look like that but I can't understand why it is adding the route enclosed in () after the link. I can't find it in my CSS, that's for sure.

Comment: @MB34, wow, that's definitely impossible to answer without you showing your entire razor view. From the code you posted, I guarantee you that  `[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]` cannot possibly render this.

Comment: Damn, I was including the print.css with it and it had this: a:link:after, a:visited:after {content:" (" attr(href) ")";font-size:90%;} That would explain it. I thought I looked at all my CSS files. Big egg on my face!!!